# Excel - Combine data from multiple tables dynamically

Tags: excel

I would like to combine three different tables in Excel. I am struggling with the fact that the tables can vary in length.
For example:

[image: table 1]
[image: table 2]
[image: table 3]

What I would like to achieve is all the tables' data in one table without empty spaces. So first the two entries from the first table then the three entries from the second table and lastly the entry from the third table. But the amount of rows in each table can vary.

[image: output table]

How can I do this dynamically so when the amount of entries in the tables change it can handle this? I'm using Mac with Office365. Thanks!

EDIT:
Output with Ron Rosenfeld's solution, the range of the list goes down from cell 5 - cell 103. Could this be reduced to 5 - 15?:
[image: intermediate solution]

Comment: You don't show any **empty spaces** in your tables. Do you mean **zero's**?  Also, what version of Excel -- Windows / Mac / Office 365 ?

Comment: "tables can vary in length.".. will the empty cells have `0` in it... or blank ?

Comment: The empty cells will have `0` in them yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 2019 or Office 365, with the `FILTERXML`  and `TEXTJOIN` functions, you can use:

```
 =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Table1,Table2, Table3) & "</s></t>","//s[.!=0]")
```

*If those zero's are really blanks, you can omit `[.!=0]` from the xPath argument, but it won't hurt to leave it there*

[image]

***Edit:***

With MAC versions of Office 365 that do not have the `FILTERXML` function, I believe the following will work:

```
=LET(
a,299,
x,IF(SEQUENCE(99,,0)=0,1,SEQUENCE(99,,0)*a),
y,TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",a),TRUE,Table19,Table20,Table21),
z, TRIM(MID(y,x,a)),FILTER(z,(z<>"0")*(z<>""))
)
```

*Note the `a` parameter in the above function*

- Because of how the splitting algorithm works, the sequence for each cell will not always start at the beginning of a string.

  - Hence, if there are enough letters in the various strings, the start number may eventually get offset enough to cause a split in the wrong location
- One fix is to use an arbitrarily large number of `space`'s to insert.
- `99` is frequently large enough, but not for this data set.
- `299` seems to be large enough for the data set as shown in your actual data.

  - *I believe the minimum number should be the sum of the lengths of all the characters in the original tables (including the `0`'s) plus one (`1`). But not sure of this.*
  - You can certainly adjust it as needed
- If the number becomes too large, you could run into the 32,767 character limitation.  If that happened, an error message would occur.

So, if you wanted to compute `a`, dynamically, you could try something like:

```
=LET(
a,SUM(LEN(Table19[Column1]),LEN(Table20[Column1]),LEN(Table21[Column1]))+1,
x,IF(SEQUENCE(99,,0)=0,1,SEQUENCE(99,,0)*a),
y,TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",a),TRUE,Table19,Table20,Table21),
z, TRIM(MID(y,x,a)),FILTER(z,(z<>"0")*(z<>""))
)
```

but no guarantees.

Comment: When I try this solution I get`#NAME?` in the output cell.

Comment: I googled and found that `filterxml` isn't available for [mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7).

Comment: @William What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have updated my question, I am using mac and office365.

Comment: @William See my Edit and check if it will work on your version and with your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm almost there the current output is almost as requested. For some reason it splits up the line. Is it also possible to have the area of the output only contain to the amount of entries? As of now it goes down quite far with all `" "`. I will update my question with the current output.

Comment: @William No problem.  See ***Edit2***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234073/discussion-between-william-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: @William Latest edit should take care of the unwanted splitting problem. And explanation is included, and only one MAC friendly formula remains.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in A:C, and empty cell is blank (not `0`).

In E1 put :

```
=IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:C),"",
    INDEX(A:C,
        IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),ROW(),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:B),ROW()-COUNTA(A:A),ROW()-COUNTA(A:B))),
        IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),1,IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:B),2,3)))    
   )
```

Idea : use `row()` to guide in selection in index. `counta()` is used guide converting 'row()' to usable index numbers. Also make the output cell blank `""` for `row()` > `counta(a:c)`.

Please share if it works/not.